# Get all keys from ruby hash

Tags: ruby

In php you can just do `$associative_array_keys = array_keys($associative_array)`

Is there a function to get all hash keys in ruby?

I'm currently mapping my hashes and returning the keys: `my_hash_keys = my_hash.map{|k,v| k}`

Is there a better solution?

Comment: For future reference, you might want to bookmark the ruby api documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/

Comment: Tried to delete this question, but after it was answered it can not be deleted. Flagging it for a mod.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call `.keys` on a Hash to get an array of keys back.

See: [Hash#keys](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-keys)

Comment: Errr... I tried keys but I was trying to use it on an array of hashes.  Saw my mistake after you answered.